# Linear Quadratic Control problem with unknown time-varying parameters in objective funtion

Tags: optimization, control-theory, quadratic-programming

How to tackle a linear quadratic control problem with unknown time-varying parameters in objective funtion, e.g., a problem with a simple state dynamic $x_{t+1}=x_{t}+u_{t}$ and cost function $$ \sum_{t=1}^{T}x_{t}^{\top}Q_{t}x_{t}+u_{t}^{\top}R_{t}u_{t}+x_{t}^{\top}N_{t}u_{t} $$ where $Q_{t}$, $R_{t}$ and $N_{t}$ could be time-varying or non-stationary but unknwon and they need to be estimated.

Are there any research papers or books talking about this topic?

Comment: Are there any assumptions about those weighting matrices? For example would it be possible that they are chosen adversarially, such that the cost function is maximized with regards to the chosen policy?

Comment: @Kwin van der Veen Yes, the situation you mentioned is related to this topic! Do you have materials for reference?

Answer (score 0):

I myself found a paper that maybe useful for future readers:
**Online Linear Quadratic Control** [enter link description here](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v80/cohen18b.html).

See also the references therein and citing papers.